# How to duplicate UpValue of one function to another?

Tags: function-construction, upvalues

Let's say I have defined a function `zO` for the following up-values

```
zO/:zO[x_]+zO[y_]:=zO[x+y];
zO/:zO[x_]+zo[y_]:=zO[x+y];
zO/:zO[x_]-zO[y_]:=zO[x+y];
```

Now I want to define another function `zOE` which have the same up-values. How can I do this without copying and modifying the above rules?

Comment: It's allowed to answer your own question. That way it's clearer that the problem was actually solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have actually solved this question myself. Simply use

```
UpValues[zOE] = (UpValues[zO]/. zO->zOE)
```